# Whats the best data-structure to store a string

Tags: data-structures

Recently I had an interview and I was asked this question.

Given a string which can have `insert`,`delete` and `substring` functions.

`substring` function returns the string from start index to end index which are given as parameters.

All three options are in random order, what is the efficient data-structure to use.

Comment: You could just mention all the data structure you thought and analyzed for the given problem. For example, "I thought of this data structure, this is good about it but I am looking for something more efficient." After all, in the interviews, not only the solution but also different approaches you thought of matter a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `insert` or `delete` operations here can be carried out in the middle of the string, not just end. Otherwise anything like c++ `vector` or python list is good enough.

Otherwise, [Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) data structure is a very good candidate. It allows all of those operations in O(logN), which i think the best anyone could hope for. It's a good choice for editors, or while manipulating huge strings, genome data for example.

Another related, and more common choice for editors is [Gap Buffer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer)

Comment: I will see about Rope data structure.